# Add three dot to the end of dynamic text android

Tags: java, android

I have to add 3 dots to the end of a text in a textview. My textView is in an lazy list adapter so the content change very often.Only two lines are shown in the textview.

e.g. suppose text is

abcdefghigdddddddd
dddddddddddddddddddd

result should be

abcdefghigdddddddd
ddddddddddddddddd...

I know i should use .replace("...","");

but how to always write off the last thre words ?

My textview is as follows

```
holder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(a.name));
```

where a.name is the data to be set.

Answer (score 4):

You can add 'elipses' attributes to your TextView, and also specify that the text view is just one line.  It could look like this:

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_value"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set your `TextView` property `android:ellipsize="end"` and you will get the result.

Comment: How many number of lines you want to show? Set the `android:maxLines="2"` for your `TextView`.

Answer (score 1):

First you fetch the text in a String. Then you fetch the length of the string. Then you can fetch the index of the third character from last. The you can easily replace the three last characters with ...

All this can be done using the methods of String class in Java.

Suppose you want to display only 4 characters from the string "raviranjan", and you want to trim all other characters by replacing them with "...". The do as following:-

```
String str = "raviranjan";
int length = str.length();
String subString = str.substring(0, 3);  // takes four characters from beginning
String str2 = subString + "...";   // Add ellipsis
```

Now str2 is the string you want....

Comment: can you give me an example

Answer (score 0):

make textView ellipsis and let android truncate it automatically for you .

```
<TextView ....... bla- bla -------
          .......................
          android:elipsis="true"
          android:lines="num_of_lines" />
```

Comment: elipsis is closely bind with singleLine/lines attrs. did you used them correctly ? share your xml layout and associated java code .

Answer (score 0):

you want to add 3 dots at end of your text then

```
holder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(a.name+"..."));
```

for remove 3 char & add 3 dots..

```
    String a = a.name;
    a.substring(0, a.length() - 3);
    holder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(a.name+"..."));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace extra characters with ellipses, you might be able to get away with something like so:

```
String str = "abcdefghigdddddddd dddddddddddddddddddd";
String newStr = str.replaceAll("^(.{100})(.*)$","$1...");
```

The above should match the first 100 characters and throw them in one group, while throw the other characters in another group. The result will be then a new string which is made up from the first group followed by 3 dots.

You can change the value of 100 to whatever amount of characters you want before the ellipses.

Comment: does it consider space too because some text does not take the "..."

Comment: @yakusha In regex, the `.` represents any character, so it should match a white space (`\s`). In the example I have, it replaces anything over 100 characters with the 1st 100 characters and 3 ellipses, so it might be the case that the text you are trying to change is shorter.

Comment: yes but all row in listview doesn't end at the last three character on third line.

Comment: @yakusha: I do not understand what you mean.